# Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; text: string; }'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting below error for below TypeScript code,

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; text: string; }'. Property 'title' is missing in type '{}'.

As I am declare "article" like below,

```
article: { title: string, text: string } = {};
```

What is the reason for it and how to resolve this? Thanks!

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'article-editor',
    template: `
    <p>Title: <input [formControl]="titleControl"></p>
    <p>Text: <input [formControl]="textControl"></p>
    <p><button (click)="saveArticle()">Save</button></p>
    <hr />
    <p>Preview:</p>
    <div style="border:1px solid #999;margin:50px;">
      <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{article.text}}</p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ArticleEditorComponent {
    article: { title: string, text: string } = {};

    titleControl: FormControl = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    textControl: FormControl = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    articleFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        title: this.titleControl,
        text: this.textControl
    });

    saveArticle() {
        if (this.articleFormGroup.valid) {
            this.article = this.articleFormGroup.value;
        } else {
            console.log('Missing field(s)!');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You told the compiler that `article` is of type `{ title: string, text: string }` but then you assign an empty object (`{}`) which lacks both `title` and `text`, so the compiler complains.

You can use type assertion to tell the compiler that it's ok:

```
let article: { title: string, text: string } = {} as { title: string, text: string };
```

You can also put that into a type alias:

```
type MyType = { title: string, text: string };
let article: MyType = {} as MyType;
```

And as you're using type assertion then you can simply:

```
let article = {} as MyType;
```

Comment: This is exactly wrong thing to do. In such case it is better to define fields as optional as suggested in another answer.

Comment: @VilmantasBaranauskas That's not true in all cases. You sometimes do want to have mandatory properties, but you just don't set them right away. This way you create the object and assign the properties.

Comment: Using the as operator is considered bad form. Please don't use it unless strictly necessary. It breaks trust in types.

Comment: It's been a long time, but for anyone in the future using `as` is still not ideal. You lose type safety and might access a property before it's defined, exactly the wrong thing to do. The better thing is to use a partial type, then use `as` after the properties are defined in the code

Answer (score 8):

The reason is quite simply that you claim `article` should have `title` and `text` fields, but `{}` doesn't. How to resolve it depends on what you want to show while `article` has the initial value, but the simplest fix would be to make the fields optional: `{ title?: string, text?: string }`.

Comment: Adding optional mitigates the problem but it introduces broader types. This might give much more boilerplate code in the application to handle the undefined case. If possible, keep a sound core with a reduced number of optional types and gate keep strictly.

Answer (score 1):

As the solution was alluded to, but not written out above, you would do:

```
article: { title?: string, text?: string } = {};
```

If an empty object is allowable, then the properties are optional. If you plan on the object always containing those properties, and you just want to define the structure, then just declare it:

```
article: { title: string, text: string };
```

In your code, there is no situation where you might use the object before its value is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a third option here for people passing by: Add sane defaults.

```
const article: { title: string, text: string } = {
    title: "default title",
    text: "default text"
};
```

It might not be applicable here, but generally it is considered good form to initialize objects to satisfy their type *and* have as tight types as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the `"type... is not assignable to type"` errors, you can do the following:

Go go the `tsconfig.json` file, and then change `"strict": true` to `"strict": false`:

[image]

I've had enough of errors like that.