# Declare an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get the following error, Can someone tell me how to resolve it ?

> Type '{ animal:[{ id : 1,name: "Elephant"},{id : 2, name: "Horse"} [];
>   }' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.   Property 'includes' is
>   missing in type '{ animal: { id: number; name: string; }[]; }'.

```
 animals : string[];
 ...

 let e = {
      animal:[
      { 
        id : 1,
        name: "Elephant"

      },
      {
        id : 2,
        name: "Horse"
      }
    ]};
    this.animals = e;
```

Comment: I believe that e is an object and not an array?

Comment: You are assigning an object that contains an animal array property to a string array.

Comment: It was a genuine question. No idea why the downvote :/

Comment: @sharonHwk, i edited your tags as this is not an angular issue but javascript / typescript

Answer (score 3):

Without changing the value of `e`, the type of animals would be:

`animals : {animal: [{id:number, name: string}]}`

You are currently trying to assign the above type into a string array, which would look like `['Elephant', 'Horse']`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091602/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-title-string-text-string) elaborates on writing your own type.

Comment: I still did not fully understand the approach. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @sharonHwk, where would you like me to elaborate on? I can try to include some more information, but the basic issue is that when you try to set `this.animals = e;`, `e` is not a `string[]` which you declared `animals` to be.