# How to create an interface for object and array of objects in Angular 8 and type script?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an interface for Object, objects, and array of objects.

Sample interface

```
export interface ErateColumn {
  categories:{
    [key:string]:column[]
  }
}

interface column {
  label:string
  value:string
}
```

Sample API response like this

```
{
"categories": {
    "Basic Information": [
        { label: "Applicant Type", value: "ApplicantType" },
        { label: "Organization Name", value: "OrganizationName" },
    ],
    "FRN Lineitem": [
        { label: "Monthly_Cost", value: "Monthly_Cost" },
        ],
    "FRN status": [
        { label: "Purpose Type", value: "PurposeType" },

    ]
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what you have provided in `this._erateColumn.next(columnList)` method is `columnList`. And somehow `columnList` seems to be a single object of the interface ErateColumn, While your BehaviorSubject has type array of ErateColumn. Change that to ErateColumn or provide array in `this._erateColumn.next(columnList)` method for your code to work.

**EDIT**

According to the new screenshot of yours, it says property `categories` is missing so either make it optional like this

```
export interface ErateColumn {
  categories?:{
    [key:string]:column[]
  }
}

interface column {
  label:string
  value:string
}
```

or provide categories.

Comment: #Parth Savaliya, I'have changed to `private readonly _erateColumn = new BehaviorSubject<ErateColumn>({} as ErateColumn)` error gone. thanks for your help. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091602/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-title-string-text-string

Comment: I'll still suggest you make fields optional rather than using your approach

Answer (score 0):

> May be this approach can help someone

You can convert **JSON** to typescript's **class** or **interface**, Using online tool [json2ts](http://json2ts.com/) or if you are using [vs code (Visual Studio)](https://code.visualstudio.com/)  use this extension [QuickType - Paste JSON as Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype)

**Note: Your JSON should be a valid JSON otherwise you will get errors**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
interface User {
   name: string;
   phone: string;
}

const user: User ==> Object

const usersList: User[] ===> Array of Objects
```